# Binary to Decimal and Hex (bit by bit)

Tags: c, binary, numbers, hex, decimal

I'm learning **C programming**. I've been given a "Challenge Task" that states that I have to get binary input from user bit by bit *(8 times, since there's 8 bits in a byte*) asking for 1 or 0 *(do not have to validate)* and them.

After collecting 8 bits, I then have to give an output

"Your decimal value for binary number is: " and then the decimal value.
"Your hexadecimal value for binary number is: " and then the hex value.

**I am not looking for answers or code, I am looking for ways to tackle this problem. Can you tell me the right approach in terms of thinking?**

I know that I'll need 8 int variables, bit1,bit2,bit3,bit4,bit5,bit6,bit7 and bit8.

Below is my code so far.
Thanks!

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{  
    int bit1,bit2,bit3,bit4,bit5,bit6,bit7,bit8;

    printf("Please enter the first bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit1);
    printf("Please enter the second bi(0 or 1)t: ");
    scanf("%d",&bit2);  
    printf("Please enter the third bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit3);  
    printf("Please enter the fourth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit4);  
    printf("Please enter the fifth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit5);  
    printf("Please enter the sixth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit6);  
    printf("Please enter the seventh bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit7);
    printf("Please enter the eigth bit:(0 or 1) ");
    scanf("%d",&bit8);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: You not need variables for each bit. You can merge each input value with the result in a loop.

Comment: The requirement of the task is to collect bit by bit.

Comment: Yes, in a loop, 1 bit per loop, 8 bits.

Comment: Not following you again I'm sorry. Can you elaborate? One thing is for sure that you need 8 variables to collect the data.

Yes you can probably merge the values of 8 of them into 1 variable. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You need **three** variables. One to control the loop, one to get the input, and one where the result is built.

Comment: If my teacher has asked me to collect it Bit by Bit (8 variables) I'll have to use that.

Is there not any way around the problem if I am using 8 variables to collect the byte?

Comment: Did your teacher actually say "use 8 variables"? Your question says "input 8 times".

Comment: Below is the exact question

You are required to construct a program that prompts user to enter an 8-bit binary
number, then it will be converted into decimal number and hexadecimal number as
output. You may request the user to input the binary number by entering one bit at a
time.
Example of program execution:
Please enter the 1st bit of your binary number (0 or 1): 1
Please enter the 2nd bit of your binary number (0 or 1): 1
Please enter the 3rd bit of your binary number (0 or 1): 0
Please enter the 4th bit of your binary number (0 or 1): 1
**the rest is too long for stackoverflow

Comment: That should be edited into the question. But as far as I can see, it does not say you must have one variable for each bit - that's your interpretation of it. So please don't be fixed in your thinking. I have given my hint, good luck.

Comment: you are looking for a concept called "bit masking", there is almost unlimited number of examples of this in every language imaginable, except maybe interactions of floating point numbers and logical operators that many languages(like vbscript) fail to make consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have declare `8` separate integers. You can collect your input to `int bit[8]` array. After that you can use array elements in a simple processing loop.

After collection is done you can construct the value of your `8` bit byte by taking under account that every collected bit in `bit[8]` has to go to the different position in your byte.

You can do that by shifting `1` according to the byte position and 'adding' it to the byte.

`<<` is the bitwise left shift operator.

You can use binary `OR` operator `'|'` to implant `1` into the proper byte position.
The binary `'|'` operation with `0` has no effect on the byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{  
    char c = 0;
    int bit[8];

   // Typically bits are counted from LS to MS where LS is bit 0   
    printf("Please enter the first bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[0]);
    printf("Please enter the second bi(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[1]);  
    printf("Please enter the third bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[2]);  
    printf("Please enter the fourth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[3]);  
    printf("Please enter the fifth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[4]);  
    printf("Please enter the sixth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[5]);  
    printf("Please enter the seventh bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[6]);
    printf("Please enter the eigth bit:(0 or 1) ");
    scanf("%d",&bit[7]);

    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        c = c | (bit[i] << i);
    }    

    printf("\nYour decimal value for binary number is: %d\n", c);
    printf("Your hexadecimal value for binary number is: x%2.2X\n", (unsigned char)c);

    return 0;        
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter the first bit(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                          
Please enter the second bi(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                          
Please enter the third bit(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                          
Please enter the fourth bit(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                         
Please enter the fifth bit(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                          
Please enter the sixth bit(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                          
Please enter the seventh bit(0 or 1): 0                                                                                                        
Please enter the eigth bit:(0 or 1) 1 

Your decimal value for binary number is: -128                                                                                                
Your hexadecimal value for binary number is: x80
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the 8 variables to store each bit. You can manage with a single variable `inputBit` to receive all the bits.

You could do this (for positive numbers) like

```
unsigned int n = 0
for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
{
    printf("Enter bit %d: ", i);
    scanf("%d", &inputBit);
    n = n + (inputBit<<i);
}
```

The resultant decimal number would be in `n` which was initialised to `0`.

`<<` is the bitwise left shift operator.

`inputBit<<i` is added to `n` on each iteration of the loop.

When `inputBit` is `1`, the value of `inputBit<<i` is same as 2<sup>i</sup> and when `inputBit` is `0`, `inputBit<<i` is `0`.

To print `n` in its hexadecimal form, do

```
printf("\nHexadecimal form: %x", n);
```

Answer (score 0):

2^7 * (1 OR 0) + 2^6 * (1 OR 0) + 2^5 * (1 OR 0) + 2^4 * (1 OR 0) + 2^3 * (1 OR 0) + 2^2 * (1 OR 0) + 2^1 * (1 OR 0) + 2^0 * (1 OR 0)

This is how you have to convert binary to decimal
(1 OR 0) is what you enter from input

Something like this if you want inputs in 8 diffrent variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

    int main()
{  
    int bit1,bit2,bit3,bit4,bit5,bit6,bit7,bit8;
int sum =0;

    printf("Please enter the first bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit1);
    printf("Please enter the second bi(0 or 1)t: ");
    scanf("%d",&bit2);  
    printf("Please enter the third bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit3);  
    printf("Please enter the fourth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit4);  
    printf("Please enter the fifth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit5);  
    printf("Please enter the sixth bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit6);  
    printf("Please enter the seventh bit(0 or 1): ");
    scanf("%d",&bit7);
    printf("Please enter the eigth bit:(0 or 1) ");
    scanf("%d",&bit8);

    sum = (pow(2,7) * bit8) + (pow(2,6) * bit7) + (pow(2,5) * bit6) 
+ (pow(2,4) * bit5) + (pow(2,3) * bit4) + (pow(2,2) * bit3) +
 (pow(2,1) * bit2) + (pow(2,0) * bit1);

printf("decimal = %d\n",sum);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: I know the process of converting from binary to decimal on paper. 

But how do I implement it in terms of programming?

Comment: collect your inputs in an array, say char input[8]; Then build your decimal by looping 
Loop 8 times to build your decimal
 sum = sum + (2^(i) * input[j])
i decreasig 7 to 0 and j increasing from 0 to 7 (assuming you enter msb first)

Comment: if the requirement of the task is to get 8 inputs from 8 variables, then how?

Comment: You would then just convert the expression from my answer in c , collect its result and print

Comment: Convert from what to what? Can you elaborate on that part? Beginner level here.